# How to select files within a directory instead of the entire directory?

Tags: c#

I am able to click on my browse button to select multiple files, but I would like to go inside of those files and select what I want. Now, it just allows me to pick the entire folder of files.

```
namespace ListPrac
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath);
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath);

                foreach(string file in files)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                }

                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dir);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FolderBrowserDialog` is used when you want the user to select a folder. If you want the user to be able to select a file, you can use `FileDialog`.

Comment: Also look into using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`, which are more performant when just iterating through.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to look into that, I am unfamiliar with how those work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Folder\";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                    foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames) 
                    {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                            //Do whatever it is you want with them
                    }
            }
        }
```

This will allow you to navigate folders. OpenFileDialog.Filename will give you the path location of the selected file so you can enumerate through the file using that.

Comment: When I use that, it allows me to go right to the filename and select it, but it does not allow me to select multiple files or display any of them when I click on it.

Comment: I've edited my answer as I forgot to add multiselect.